# Proper MIME media type for JNLP files

Tags: http-headers, mime-types, content-type, jnlp

When working with JNLP files, I've run across the MIME type

> application/x-java-jnlp-file

However I am not sure it is right, because

> MIME types in the x- namespace are considered experimental

and it seems odd to me for JNLP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the advice direct from Oracle in [Setting Up the Web Site:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/setup.html)

> 1. Configure the Web server to use the Java Web Start MIME type
>
> Configure the Web server so that all files with the .jnlp file extension are set to the `application/x-java-jnlp-file` MIME type.
>
> Most Web browsers use the MIME type returned with the contents from the Web server to determine how to handle the particular content. The server must return `application/x-java-jnlp-file` MIME type for JNLP files in order for Java Web Start to be invoked.
>
> Each Web server has a specific way in which to add MIME types. For example, for the Apache Web server you must add the following line to the .mime.types configuration file:
>
> ```
>    application/x-java-jnlp-file JNLP
> ```
>
> Check the documentation for the specifics of your Web server.